# Не работает поиск максимального из бд mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу найти максимальное кол-во денег в таблице и вывести. Не работает. В чем проблема?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "root", "moneysuccesslife");
$mysqli->query("SETNAMES 'utf8'");
echo($mysqli->query("SELECT MAX(money) FROM user"));
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Что значит «не работает»? Что происходит вместо работы?

Comment: mysqli->query возвращает объект результата. Вывести его эхом не выйдет. Посмотрите тут. например, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: не выводит ничего. ничё не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<?php
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT MAX(money) FROM user");

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$mysqli->close();

print_r($row);
```

[Test PHP online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/6be0a54dab33f36e421a0d67e8b3221b/php/php8/d73c1a5ce7095b1a8ae3f4be99a408d9/)